# How to indicate make program for XCode 5.1 C++ project?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, xcode5

I have created new C++ project in XCode 5.1 (Console tool project), now I want to use a make script (named make-arm) instead of default Apple SDK make program, how can I do that?

**EDIT:** I have tried to create a external build project but it seem doen't support code sense (code auto completion) for C++.